# cURL to soundcloud.com returns 500

Tags: ubuntu, curl, request, soundcloud

I'm getting the following 500 response after attempting to curl from my

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

server.

```
# curl -vvv -L soundcloud.com
* Rebuilt URL to: soundcloud.com/
*   Trying 72.21.91.127...
* Connected to soundcloud.com (72.21.91.127) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: soundcloud.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Content-Type: text/html
< Date: Sat, 01 Oct 2016 05:03:52 GMT
< Server: am/2
< Content-Length: 87
<
<html><body><h1>500 Server Error</h1>
An internal server error occured.
</body></html>
* Connection #0 to host soundcloud.com left intact
```

What is mysterious is that is was working a couple days ago. A curl to github.com is returning a 200, so I don't think there is an issue with my network connection. I have just done a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` right before posting this question. On my laptop, the same requests gives back a 200. If I'm being rate-limited, I should be getting back a 429. I'm confused what is happening on my server. Is there anything I can do to debug? Am I totally missing something?

Update: Using a proxy `curl -vvv -L --proxy <random_http_proxy>:3128 http://soundcloud.com` gives back a 200. I'm so confused.

Update 2: Using https:// doesn't help

```
root@cap:~# curl -vvv -L https://soundcloud.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://soundcloud.com/
*   Trying 72.21.91.127...
* Connected to soundcloud.com (72.21.91.127) port 443 (#0)
* found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 692 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*    server certificate verification OK
*    server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*    common name: *.soundcloud.com (matched)
*    server certificate expiration date OK
*    server certificate activation date OK
*    certificate public key: RSA
*    certificate version: #3
*    subject: OU=Domain Control Validated,CN=*.soundcloud.com
*    start date: Wed, 10 Feb 2016 10:19:25 GMT
*    expire date: Wed, 09 May 2018 10:08:48 GMT
*    issuer: C=BE,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,CN=GlobalSign Domain Validation CA - SHA256 - G2
*    compression: NULL
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: soundcloud.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Content-Type: text/html
< Date: Sun, 09 Oct 2016 20:58:53 GMT
< Server: am/2
< Content-Length: 87
<
<html><body><h1>500 Server Error</h1>
An internal server error occured.
</body></html>
* Connection #0 to host soundcloud.com left intact
```

## Update 3

The problem just magically fixed itself in the sense that it suddenly just started working again. I did send a support request to soundcloud.com and the problem was gone the next day. I did not receive a response that they indeed did take any action such as whitelisting my ip address but I'm going to assume that is what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the  protocol prefix https://

```
curl -vvv -L https://soundcloud.com
```

I am not familar with the command line options.

when I used PHP curl with these options, it worked.

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE
```

The key option required is  `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE` 
  FOLLOWLOCATION is only needed for `http://` and not `https://`

**Returns a 400 Bad Request rather than 500**

---

---

### UPDATE

I was able to get a 200 HTTP response code by adding a request header that looks just like a Browser request, but the page is created using JavaScript.  So the page says "JavaScript is disabled..."

Comment: Was able to get a 200 HTTP Response, See UPDATE

Comment: Well I am getting a 200 on another server…I'm starting to think my IP address is blacklisted or something. Is there any other possible explanation?

Comment: It does not matter, because you need JavaScript to create the HTML.  Turn off JavaScript on your Browser and you will not be able to access the page.